# iOS: Posting code blocks within userInfo using NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Can i safely post messages containing code blocks within my program address space? Tests works but is this legal?

```
typedef void (^EmitBlock)(NSDictionary* args);


- (void) subscribe {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(on_emit:) name:kEmit object:nil];
}


- (void) on_emit:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    EmitBlock completion = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"completion"];
    completion(@{@"result" : @"Ok"});
}


- (void) post:(EmitBlock) completion {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kEmit
        object:nil userInfo:@{@"completion":
            ^(NSDictionay* args) { NSLog(@"%@", args); }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocks are Objective-C objects, so you *can* put them into an dictionary and use them
in the userinfo of a notification.

But note that according to the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> … You still need to use `[^{} copy]` when passing “down” the stack into
>   `arrayWithObjects:` and other methods that do a retain.

you should put a copy of the block into the dictionary:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kEmit"
    object:nil
    userInfo:@{
         @"completion" : [^(NSDictionary* args) { NSLog(@"%@", args); } copy]
     }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one from libraries, for example https://github.com/cflesner/NSNotificationCenter-CLFBlockNotifications for using blocks with notifications

I think it is more safer approach

Comment: CLFBlockNotification is just "simplification" with subscribe/unsubscribe code required for each code block. I need one subscribe/unsubscribe on receiver with code blocks distributed across all code, declared in the places where they are required by send logic.